# Is there any particular desktop environment which android uses and is there any way to get on on Ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-environments

As android is based on Linux, it might have a desktop environment. So is it possible to get it on Ubuntu or at least build it from source to use it on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not inside Ubuntu as such, but you could dual boot the computer by running [Android on Intel](https://01.org/android-ia/)

Comment: Yes I do that on a live CD, but just was curious about using it on Ubuntu.